# Как в Python 3 можно создать тип запись?

Tags: python-3.x, структуры-данных, типы-данных, запись

Имеется в виду аналог типа *record* в Паскале 
(последовательность переменных указанного при создании типа, связанных одним общим именем)?

Общий вид описания типа *record* в Паскаль:

```
var <имя_записи> = record 
<имя_поля1>:<тип_поля1>;
<имя_поля2>:<тип_поля2>; 
... end;
```

Пример использования в коде:

```
var coord = record
    x: integer;
    y: integer;
    end;

begin

coord.x:= 5;

end.
```

Comment: Не все, кто знаком с питоном, знакомы и с тонкостями паскаля, как и наоброт, поэтому покажите пример того, чего хочется.

Comment: В Python для этого используются классы.

Comment: Автор хочет, чтобы можно было использовать `Point.X` и `Point.Y`, а не Point[0]` и `Point[1]`

Comment: Общий вид описания типа record в Паскаль:
var <имя_записи> = record
     <имя_поля1>:<тип_поля1>;
     <имя_поля2>:<тип_поля2>;
     ...
 end;
То есть правильно я понимаю, что в Python нельзя сделать сборку нескольких переменных разных типов, к которым можно обращаться через одно имя (переменную-запись) с уточнением конкретного поля, кроме как объявить класс? По другому точно никак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ нашёл сам, опираясь на подсказку  @insolor (спасибо ему). Eсли кому-то будет интересно, то создать в Python аналогичную структуру данных можно используя модуль `collections`, а именно класс `collections.namedtuple`.

Этот класс  позволяет создать тип данных, ведущий себя как кортеж, с тем дополнением, что каждому элементу присваивается имя, по которому можно в дальнейшем получать доступ:

```
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(x=1, y=2)
>>> p.x
>>> 1
```